# change checkbox by another checkbox inside the event

Tags: c#, winforms, checkbox

In a winforms application, I have a situation.
That one checkbox should be disabled when a certain checkbox is checked.
I know it isn't an ideal design, but currently quite a lot depends on this and so I wonder how to make the code below work, as it would be the smallest change to the large code base.

```
private void cbCalibrate_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    CheckState CalibrationBussy;
    CalibrationBussy = cbDenoise.CheckState;
    cbDenoise.Checked = false;
    cbDenoise.Show();                      // the cbDenoise checkbox doesnt change
    cbDenoise.CheckState = CalibrationBussy;
    cbDenoise.Show();
}
```

Update i should use Checked instead of checkstate but still the problem remains. (as Checked  is actually enabled vs disabled), where checkedstate has a 3th option as not determined (user didnt touch the control).

```
        bool CalibrationBussy;
        CalibrationBussy = cbDenoise.Checked;
        cbDenoise.Checked =false;
        cbDenoise.Show();
        cbDenoise.Checked = CalibrationBussy;
        cbDenoise.Show();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 public void cbCalibrate_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            CheckState CalibrationBussy;
            SatusBeforeCalibrating = cbDenoise.CheckState;
            if ( cbDenoise.Checked == true)
            {
                account = "Active";
                cbDenoise.Show();   
            }
            else if ( cbDenoise.Checked  == false)
            {
                account = "Deactive";
              cbDenoise.Show();   
            }
        }
```

Comment: CheckState not used? why not omit?

Comment: checked state was indeed wrong, however the problem seams to be in cbDenoise.Show  it doesnt update while inside the cbCalibrate event.

Comment: Oh crap... i see the problem, i ran out of cofee

Comment: "i see the problem", the problem, cbDenoise.show worked, but in the same event it was disabled and enabled, while indeed i should have looked to the state of cbCalibrate, (if that one is checked, then disable the other) your code works too so granted.

Answer (score 0):

Use this simple template:

```
public void cbCalibrate_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
checkBox1.Enabled = checkBox2.Checked;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That will fix your problem

```
CheckState Before;
private void cbCalibrate_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(cbCalibrate.Checked == true)
    {
    Before = cbDenoise.CheckState;
    cbDenoise.Enabled = false;
    cbDenoise.Checked = false;
    }
    if(cbCalibrate.Checked == false && Before = true)
    {
        cbDenoise.Checkd = true
        cbDenoise.Enabled = true;
    }
}
```